# remove items in local storage based on the cms data updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I need to remove an item from the `localStorage` based on the fact that it was deleted from the CMS data.

So, I need to access `cmsData` `collectionId` in my `useEffect()` hook and give to each of the collections a new state. I have an access to the IDs though `cmsData` but I'm not sure how should I check for changes and assign a new state to each of collections in the `useEffect()` hook.

(Now my code just resets the whole `localStorage` on the reload.)

Could you give me a hint?

```js
import React = require("react");
import {PropsWithChildren, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {CollectionId} from "../../DataTypes";
import {ExpandingContext, ExpandingInfo} from "../../Expanding";
import {useCmsData} from "../../api/CmsDataProvider";

function ExpandControllerComponent (props: PropsWithChildren<any>) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(() => getPersistState())
    const cmsData = useCmsData();

    useEffect(() => {
        cleanUpPersistState()
    }, [])

    const expandingInfo: ExpandingInfo = {
        state: state,
        toggleExpand: collectionId => {
           setState((state) => {
               const isExpanded = expandingInfo.state.get(collectionId) ?? true
               state.set(collectionId, !isExpanded)
               const newState = new Map<CollectionId, boolean>(state)
               persistState(newState)
               return newState
           })
        },
    }

    return (
        <ExpandingContext.Provider value={expandingInfo}>
            {props.children}
        </ExpandingContext.Provider>
    )
}

const persistenceKey = "expandingState"

function persistState (state: Map<CollectionId, boolean>) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(Array.from(state.entries()))
    localStorage.setItem(persistenceKey, json)
}

function getPersistState (): Map<CollectionId, boolean> {
    const json = localStorage.getItem(persistenceKey)
    return new Map(JSON.parse(json))
}

function cleanUpPersistState () {
    localStorage.removeItem(persistenceKey);
}

export = ExpandControllerComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for changes in `useEffect` Hook by `useEffect({},[cmsData])`, if `cmsData` gets some value assigned or updated it the `useEffect` will run. Be careful `useEffect` will also run on page load and only run when `cmsData` values changes. Further more you can also listen for other variable by `useEffect({}, [cmsData, otherVar, etc])` by this way useEffect will also listen for those variables and run when any of the values provided in the array changes.

Comment: thanks, and what should I write inside useEffect() in order to clean up only the state of the changed collections?

Comment: or better say, I need to define a functionality in function `cleanUpPersistState () {
    localStorage.removeItem(persistenceKey);
}`